# How to edit graphs by graphviz?

Tags: c, open-source, graphviz

Is any one familiar with any c open source code that does graph manipulation (point and click) using the layout algorithms of graph viz? I would like to use the algorithms to lay out a graph which I could later manipulate in a GUI.

Comment: What you are asking for makes no sense. Graphviz is a tool to come up with a layout of a graph. If you want to lay out a graph manually, you don't need graphviz and if you want to define a graph graphically, you don't need graphviz either. Please, rewrite the question to include the actual goal you have.

Comment: @Jan Hudec I updated the question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

graphviz C code and architecture are rather sophisticated. You can take a look at [canviz](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/). It's Javascript rendering engine that you could port to C.

Some time ago I tried the qt way, following [this](http://mupuf.org/blog/article/34/) post, but that wasn't an easy route.